# Dimension bound on invertible bimodules for blocks

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

A co-author and I have recently proved the following result:

Theorem.
Let $B$ be a block of a finite group defined over some algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$. If $M$ is a $B$-$B$-bimodule inducing a Morita auto-equivalence of $B$ then $\dim_k(M)\leq \dim_k(B)$.

In fact it holds for any finite dimensional $k$-algebra whose Cartan matrix is symmetric and positive definite. My question is whether this is already known/written down? If the block is defined over a suitable complete, discrete valuation ring, then the result is a bit easier as one can use ordinary characters but is it already known over $k$?

Any help would be much appreciated.